# How to exclude K8s resource attributes from traces created with opentelemetry?

Tags: kubernetes, trace, open-telemetry

I am using the Opentelemetry Operator on a K8s cluster to auto instrument my java application through the Instrumentation CR and send traces first to the Grafana Agent and then to the Tempo backend that uses Grafana to visualise the traces. I cannot get rid of the following resource attributes on the visualisation:
`k8s.container.name, k8s.deployment.name, k8s.namespace.name, k8s.node.name, k8s.pod.name, k8s.replicaset.name`

I managed to exclude attributes from other resources as Os, Host or Container from the Instrumentation CR with the following spec.java.env (:

```
- name: OTEL_JAVA_DISABLED_RESOURCE_PROVIDERS
  value: io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.resources.OsResourceProvider,io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.resources.HostResourceProvider,io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.resources.ContainerResourceProvider
```

But I cannot find the corresponding value to disable the K8s resource provider. Anyone has this answer?

Tried:

- name: OTEL_JAVA_DISABLED_RESOURCE_PROVIDERS
- value: io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.resources.K8sResourceProvider
  or
- value: io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.resources.K8SResourceProvider
  or
- value: io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.resources.KubernetesResourceProvider

Comment: I would guess these are related more to the collector using the attributeprocessor than the application generating them. So have a look at the generator collector config as a starting point.

Comment: yes the Otel collector has that function (https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/configuration/#processors) but I'm using the Grafana Agent as collector, so I was wondering if there is a way to do the same with it